# convert HTML5 to mobile app and use pop out messages

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, social-networking

is it possible to convert web (social)network made in HTML5 to mobile app? And then enable pop out messages for android and iOs?
If not, what would you suggest?

I'm trying to make some kind of social network and I'm having trobles deciding how to do it. I'd like to make an app and put it on app store or i-store. I know how to do it with html5 and java script, but I don't know how to convert it in to app and give it function of a pop up messages.

Comment: question is unclear can you please explain in detail!

Comment: What do you mean by `convert`? A tool, which will do the magic, so you give it HTML, and it returns you mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

you can search for progressive web app(PWA) development which enables you to do this